# Can anyone help me with creating an attribute based access control in solidity?

Tags: solidity

I am trying to implement ABAC but couldn't find any helpful resources

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you maybe took a look at accessControl library from OpenZeppelin? It might be exactly what you need.

Comment: Can you leave this as a comment instead of an answer? Thank you!

Comment: OpenZeppelin only helps to create RBAC.

Comment: @vishnugg could you specify more directly what kind of functionality you would like? I might be able to help then.